# Typescript can i use generic type in function body

Tags: typescript

i have function declaration like this:

```js
export const filterOptions: <OptionValueType>(
  options: OptionsArray<OptionValueType>,
  filterBy: string
) => OptionsArray<OptionValueType> = (options, filterBy) => {
  if (filterBy === "") {
    return [...options];
  } else {
    const filteredOptions: OptionsArray<OptionValueType> = [];
    // filter and return options

    return [...filteredOptions];
  }
};
```

but, typescript mark this code as Error, can we use generic types in function body ?

```js
const filteredOptions: OptionsArray<OptionValueType> = [];
```

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'OptionValueType'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the generic type parameter in the body, but the generic type parameter has to be on the function implementation not on the variable that will hold the function

```js
export const filterOptions = <OptionValueType>(
  options: OptionsArray<OptionValueType>,
  filterBy: string
): OptionsArray<OptionValueType> => {
  if (filterBy === "") {
    return [...options];
  } else {
    const filteredOptions: OptionsArray<OptionValueType> = [];
    // filter and return options

    return [...filteredOptions];
  }
};
```

Comment: You save my day! Thank you.

Comment: But with this, it would be impossible to separate type definitions into a separate file (in cases like this), could be better if typescript suppoted this behavior